# Editor Loop delay. Is it a problem for my game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

**I'm new on that thing of analisys profile of Unity. I decided to see if my player is dropping too much FPS and the I found this. Will that be a problem for my game? I don't know how that system works, but I guess 8.35 is a high number...**

[image: Analisys profile]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's not.

The editor loop is how long the unity editor took.

The player loop is (roughly) the performance of your game. And the big green part looks like the `WaitForTargetFPS` call to me. Though to tell for sure you'd have to expand the player loop and see.

If you want to measure the actual performance of your game accurately you have to make a development build and profile that one (you can select the debugging options for this in the build dialog).

Further reading: [profiler documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerCPU.html)